# как остановить функцию

Tags: javascript, canvas, таймер

Нужно чтобы после прохождения полного круга действие не повторялось. Как это сделать?
[Пример кода на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/YuriWeb/n9jq7ncs/)

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" ></canvas>
<script>
  var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
    context = myCanvas.getContext("2d"),
    timeLimit = 15E3,
    timeStart = (new Date).getTime(),
    canvasSize = 200,
    lineWidth = 24,
    drawX = drawY = radius = canvasSize / 2;
    radius -= lineWidth / 2;
    myCanvas.width = canvasSize;
    myCanvas.height = canvasSize;

function go() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    context.lineCap = "round";
    context.strokeStyle = "rgb(0, 255, 0)";
    var a = ((new Date).getTime() - timeStart) / timeLimit;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasSize, canvasSize);
    context.font = '24px "Tahoma"';
    context.fillText((10 - a*10)|0, radius, drawY);
    context.arc(drawX, drawY, radius, -Math.PI / 2 + 2 * Math.PI * a, -Math.PI / 2, !1);
    context.stroke();
    1 < a && (timeStart = (new Date).getTime());
    timer = window.setTimeout(go, 50)
}
go();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Или так:
после строчки:

```
context.fillText((10 - a*10)|0, radius, drawY);
if((10 - a*10)<0) return false;
```

Тогда в отличие от примера выше, останется пустая шкала.

Comment: Работает. Благодарю

Comment: хорошо. тогда отметьте решением + можно проголосовать, что ответ полезен, если не в курсе механики проекта..

Comment: не понимаю что сделать

Comment: ничего сложного, тут так принято, ответ полезен - помечаете его принятым или если репутации хватает, голосуете. Подробнее можно посмотреть здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Если добавить

```
if(a > 1) clearTimeout(timer);
```

после последней строчки, то таймер остановиться на одном прохождении круга.